# Oracle/PostgreSQL date level connect by query

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, oracle11g

I have requirement where if date date is between first and 3rd of month it should return all dates of previous month minus 3 days

And date till day minus 3 days if date is 4th or above.

if today's date is  02-AUG-2017 then

```
01-JUL-2017
02-JUL-2017
.
.
.
30-JUL-2017
```

if today's date is  03-AUG-2017 then

```
01-JUL-2017
02-JUL-2017
.
.
.
.
31-JUL-2017
```

If today's date is  04-AUG-2017 then

```
01-AUG-2017
```

and if today's date is  06-AUG-2017 then

```
 01-AUG-2017
 02-AUG-2017
 03-AUG-2017
```

query for second part is  as below

```
SELECT trunc(ADD_MONTHS((LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)),-1)+level) FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL<=to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate),'DD'))-3
```

I need to query to handle  for date's between 1st and 3rd of the month

query needed in both Oracle and Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you use `generate_series()` for this:

```
with limits (start_date, end_date) as (
   select case 
            when extract(day from current_date) <= 3 then 
                (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' month)::date
            else date_trunc('month', current_date)::date
          end, 
          case 
            when extract(day from current_date) <= 3 
              then date_trunc('month', current_date)::date - 3
            else current_date - 3
          end
)
select dt
from limits, generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1' day) as x(dt);
```

The CTE calculates the start and end date (you could use almost the same for Oracle) and then generate_series() is used to get all dates between the start and the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the oracle solution for Part 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Trunc(prev_mon_dt, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 AS days
        FROM   (SELECT CASE
                         WHEN To_char(To_date('02-08-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD')
                              IN
                              ( '01', '02', '03' ) THEN
                         Add_months(To_date('02-08-2016'
                                    ,
                                    'DD-MM-YYYY'),
                         -1)
                       END prev_mon_dt
                FROM   dual)
        CONNECT BY Trunc(Trunc(prev_mon_dt, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'MM') = Trunc(
                   prev_mon_dt, 'MM'))
WHERE  To_date('02-08-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - days >= 3;
```